# cant refresh a JTextArea Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I know there is a lot of questions with the same title, I read them all, but none of their solutions worked for me.My problem is, at first the JTextArea has  to be empty, but when I click a JList element it has to display a meteorologic prediction. But when I click that element on JList with his listener, the JTextArea does not update, it keeps empty. This is my code:

```
public void textoInfoMunicipio (){

    //JTextArea area = new JTextArea(30,50);


    area.setEditable(false);


    JPanel content = new JPanel();
    content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    content.add(area,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    content.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black)); //con esto le ponemos un borde negro en los margenes del JPANEL
    content.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Predicciones"));


    IPrediccionService ps = new AEMETPrediccionService();
    List<IPrediccion> lista;


    try {

        if(arranque_app == false && municipio_seleccionado != null){ // si la aplicacion ya ha arrancado, entonces podemos mostrar la info de las predicciones
            String header = ""
                    + "********************************************************************* \n"
                    + "Predicción para el municipio de "+municipio_seleccionado.getNombre()+"\n"
                    + "********************************************************************* \n"
                    + "Fecha \t Temp.mín/máx \t Estado del cielo \n";
            lista = ps.getPrediccionesByIdMunicipio(municipio_seleccionado.getCodMunicipio()); //DESCOMENTAR, ES PA AHORRAR PETICIONES AL SERVIDOR AEMET
            String predicciones = "";
            // Recorrido de la lista mostrando solamente las predicciones
            for ( IPrediccion p : lista )
            predicciones += p.getFecha()+"\t"+p.getTemperaturaMinima()+"/"+p.getTemperaturaMaxima()+"\t\t"+p.getEstadoCielo()+"\n";
            area.setText(header+predicciones); //funciona, se ve bien 
            //content.revalidate();
            //content.repaint();
            //area.update(area.getGraphics());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) { //PrediccionServiceException e
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridwidth = 3;
    gbc.gridheight = 8;
    gbc.weightx = 1.0;
    gbc.weighty = 1.0;


    panel_principal.add(content, gbc);


}
```

In the listener event, I mean, when an element in JList is selected, I call the function above. Hope you can help me

Comment: Have you checked if the click on the JList item, actually goes in to a listener, with some sort of println

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: yes, I debugged it and I put a breakpoint in the line inside that if and it enters, so that code executes for sure!

Comment: and yes, it enters in the listener that I have

Answer (score 0):

> when an element in JList is selected, I call the function above

Well your code makes no sense. You create a new JPanel, but not a JTextArea. Then you add the text area to the panel. A component can only have a single parent, so the text area will be removed from the first panel.  Also a text area is typically added to a JScrollPane and then you add the scrollpane to the panel.

```
gbc.gridx = 1;
```

Your usage of the GridBagLayout seems incorrect to me.

1) Not sure is gridwidth/height is doing what you think. You only add a single component to the panel so you can't just randomly use values of 3/8 unless you have added other components in other parts of your code.

2) You use a gridx of "1" every time you add a panel. All panels will go in the same cell. This may be your problem. The last component added is painted first. So, you may have other panels painting over top of the panel you just added.

```
for ( IPrediccion p : lista )
predicciones += p.getFecha()+"\t"+p.getTemperaturaMinima()+"/"+p.getTemperaturaMaxima()+"\t\t"+p.getEstadoCielo()+"\n";
area.setText(header+predicciones);
```

Write readable code with proper indentation. Give spacing between the code for the loop and code outside the loop. The above looks like you have multiple lines of code in the loop.

In and case a better way to add text to the text area is to use the `append(...)` method then you don't have all that code in a long statement. Or use a StringBuilder to built the text string.

Also, since you are using tabs, this tell me you are trying to arrange the data in columns. A JTextArea is not the best component for this. Instead you should be using a `JTable`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Step y step. The JTextArea is instanciated in another parr of the code, Secondly, about the grid bag, yeah, I mean, my program at a whole is compound by several JPanels which inside there are components, and the places of the components are ok. What I just  tested is, if I put the line "content.add(area,BorderLayout.CENTER);" above of the line "panel_principal.add(content, gbc);" what happens is that, the text doesnt appear, but if I drag clicking with the mouse over the space where the JTextArea is, the text is appearing, Hopes can help to solve it

Comment: solve it, The JPanel was instaciated several types, I put an if condition and it works, I dont understand 100% why but It worked